# Funny rendering on Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using:

Google Chrome: version 118.0.5993.88 (official build) (64-bit)
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

I've updated and upgraded everything and have some strange renders on the pages, like the attached images.

In my chrome://flags/ I have enabled "Override software rendering list" and disabled: "Hardware accelerated video decoding" and after that, some sites are still showing with some pixelation issues,

Any ideas how I can fix this?

[image: sample 1]

[image: sample 2]

EDIT:

This is my system information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex [1022:15d0]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 IOMMU [1022:15d1]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:01.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0] [1022:15d3]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:01.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0] [1022:15d3]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus A [1022:15db]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:15dc]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 0 [1022:15e8]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 1 [1022:15e9]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 2 [1022:15ea]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 3 [1022:15eb]
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 4 [1022:15ec]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 5 [1022:15ed]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 6 [1022:15ee]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Device 24: Function 7 [1022:15ef]
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.2 Combo Adapter (MU-MIMO supported)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, rtl8821ce
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c1)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller [1002:15de]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:15df]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp
03:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1 [1022:15e0]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.4 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven USB 3.1 [1022:15e1]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x
03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Non-Sensor Fusion Hub KMDF driver [1022:15e6]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Sensor Fusion Hub [1022:15e4]
    Kernel driver in use: i2c_amd_mp2
    Kernel modules: i2c_amd_mp2_pci
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx [103c:8615]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Comment: @raffa Why do you feel this is an update issue? This looks like an issue with the graphics driver. Obviously, OP should make system information available.

Comment: Hi @vanadium That's what I thought at first, but a graphics driver would affect other apps as well and OP says hardware acceleration is disabled ... Therefore, low probability of graphics driver and higher probability google-chrome rendering issue ... I think

Comment: Hi @Raffa yes, that solved the issue, probably a chrome extension or some setting was causing the issue, thanks